# Android - FCM Push Notification not received after click_action is included

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to receive a Push notification when application state is both in Foreground and Background.

It was working fine before the `click_action` is added but after adding it does not make the push notification received when the application is background or killed. After some research, I could understand that I will not be able to receive the Push in Background if the FCM is "notification" message type but only "data" message type.

As FCM provides `click_action` attribute by default and also provides the method `getClickAction()` to get it in `onMessageReceived()`,  Should I really use `click_action` in data message ?

The bundle in `onMessageReceived`

```
Bundle[{
    google.sent_time = 1521177008895,
    google.ttl = 3600,
    gcm.notification.e = 1,
    lastName = Test,
    profileUrl = ,
    roleId = ,
    userId = 140128,
    gcm.notification.badge = 1,
    gcm.notification.sound =
    default,
    gcm.notification.title = Someone
    try to login with your credentials,
    roleName = ,
    userName = test,
    flag = 0,
    from = 612005318045,
    type = 0,
    gcm.notification.sound2 = simpleSound,
    firstName = Test,
    gcm.notification.notification_id = 1140,
    google.message_id = 0: 1521177008900292 % c05b1316c05b1316,
    notification = Someone
    try to login with your credentials,
    gcm.notification.body = Someone
    try to login with your credentials,
    gcm.notification.icon = myApp,
    notificationId = 2047669,
    gcm.notification.notification_type = 1,
    gcm.notification.click_action = com.my.push.activities.OPEN_NOTIFICATION_LIST,
    gcm.notification.notification_message = TEST MESSAGE,
    notificationDate = Fri Mar 16 05: 10: 08 GMT 2018,
    collapse_key = com.my.push,
    gcm.notification.notification_title = APP
}]
```

The code snippet of the way it is handled in `onMessageReceived`

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        ......
        ......
        showNotification(remoteMessage);
    }



public void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        try {
            Map<String, String> response = remoteMessage.getData();

            Intent intent = prepareIntent(remoteMessage);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "D4E_ANDROID")
                    .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                    .setContentText(response.get("notification"))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.d4e_logo)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.view_icon, "View", pIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(response.get("notificationId")), builder.build());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e("OnREC", exception.toString());
        }

    }


 public Intent prepareIntent(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> response = remoteMessage.getData();
        Intent intent;
        boolean isAppInBackground;
        if (SessionContext.isLoggedIn()) {
          isAppInBackground = SessionHelper.initializeSessionHelper().isAppInBackground(this);
                Log.e("LOGGGGG", isAppInBackground + "");
                if (isAppInBackground) {
                    intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction());
                }
            }
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        }


        return intent;
    }
```

Please anyone guide me to find the solution.

Comment: you have issue with your backend..your android part looks fyn

Comment: @Santanu Can you please guide me based on the bundle I have shared what has to be changed in backend ?

Answer (score 0):

if you can receive FCM notification sent through console, then potentially something is wrong with build the notification. one suspect is that you are not using "icon" field.
If you can debug android device, set breakpoint here and see if you get error or missed some resource.
    https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/evollu/react/fcm/SendNotificationTask.java#L46

Comment: The logs too not printed when the app is in background but printed in Foreground state

Comment: See this:                                     
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/android/push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Messages sent from the Firebase Notifications console are treated as notification-only message payloads (unless you add in a custom key-value pair, then it becomes a notification and data together).

notification-only message payload behavior is when the app is in background, the Android System will handle the notification. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages for Android for more details on the behavior.